# How to force clients to update application at startup with VB.NET project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, clickonce

We have a project written in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2008 that is to be installed on 17 client machines.

We are in the process of launching the project and came accross an issue.

We have created an installer from within Visual Studio and ran the setup.exe on a client machine. All works well but if in the meanwhile we release another update, at startup the user gets a notification saying that a new version of the project is available.

Here is the link to the image as I do not have enough reputation to upload images:
http://postimage.org/image/7l7w6u841/

The problem is that the message box that pops up has an "OK" and "Cancel" button and if the users accidently click "Cancel" their program will not be updated which means that they will be running an older version which can cause issues.

My question is: Is there a way to force the user to update the project at startup, almost like "You either update or you cannot login" type of thing?

Thanks for your time and any help will be greatly appreciated

Fil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way might be:

- Have the info about being the latest version number be available on the server
- Have the application check this before logon
- failed request should use the number of the running version
- have the application compare this value with the running version and disallow logon if bigger

**Edit**

Here is some pseudocode, assuming the newest version number is at http://somewhe.re/version.txt

```
//Application start

System.Reflection.AssemblyName an=new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
Version current_version=an.Version;

String httptext;
Version server_version=current_version;
try {
  httptext=//Result from http://somewhe.re/version.txt
  server_version=new Version(httptext);
} catch {}

if (server_version>current_version) {
  //You must update!
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Is there any way you can provide me with some sample code or pseudocode on how to accomplish this?

Comment: thank you. The problem is that once they click cancel they will not get the messagebox again prompting to update on next logon. The only way for them to update after they click cancel is for us to release another update and republish the project. Is there a way to tell VB.NET to run updater by using code? Something like 'if version<CurrentVersion then My.Project.RunUpdate' ?

Comment: Can you not just provide a linke to the update installer when telling the user about the necessity to update? User clicks the link and updates manually.

Comment: How can I find out what the link to the installer is or where it is located? I am not sure how to accomplish as I am using Visual Studio's ClickOnce settings to publish and on startup the program checks for updates itself (which is handy)

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer this. We do not use ClickOnce. You should ask this as a speratae question: I am sure, somebody here at SO knows and it might be of interest for a lot of readers!

Comment: I shall do that @Eugen. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: can i just ask what do you use do deploy your projects?

Comment: We create our Desktop apps **exclusivly** in a way, that allows "xcopy deployment" - i.e. just copy a folder to the client and start the *.exe. This has to do with the fact, that less than a third of our users are on Windows, with Ubuntu taking first place followed by Apple (Both using Mono ofcourse). Windows is on the way out: After the Vista debacle most replacements went into Linux or Mac, and the Windows 8 previews have accelerated the trend.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ClickOnce, this can be done by specifying the minimum required version

> *There may be occasions when you want to require users to run an updated version of your application. For example, you might make a change to an external resource such as a Web service that would prevent the earlier version of your application from working correctly. In this case, you would want to mark your update as required and prevent users from running the earlier version.
>
> To mark an update as required, click Specify a minimum required version for this application in the Application Updates dialog box, and then specify the publish version (Major, Minor, Build, Revision), which specifies the lowest version number of the application that can be installed. For more information, see Application Updates Dialog Box.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e(v=vs.100).aspx (Scroll down to **Making Updates Required**)

Comment: thank you for your reply. Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to automatically set the required version to the current version at each Build/Publish or will I have to manually go in after each Build/Publish and set the required version to the current one?

Comment: I don't know, but if there isn't, you can always create a click once application using mage --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.100).aspx